# How do I make html run a javascript function when a user clicks a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web form where users will type in a name of a person then click a button to open a page about that person. e.g. They type Player One and it runs a function which opens the file C:\PlayerOne.

I've tried using the `<button>` tag and adding the `onclick` element to run the function, but I was unable to diagnose the problem there either. The Event Listener stuff I am not too familiar with, but I saw it [here] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button) so I thought I'd try it that way instead.

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter player name: </legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>

  <script>
    const input = document.querySelector('button');
    input.addEventListener('click', UseData);
    function UseData()
        {
        var Fname=document.GetElementById('firstname');
        var Lname=document.GetElementById('lastname');
        window.location = "C:\" + Fname + Lname;
        }
  </script>
</form>
```

I want the user to be able to type the name and open the appropriate file, as explained above. However, the button at this point simply does nothing. I do have a test file for it to reference, which I have been typing the name of in the fields of the form.

Comment: `GetElementById` is wrong `getElementById` is correct

Comment: It's as important to know how to debug as it is to know the syntax and model of the language/technology. I recommend opening your page in Chrome and hitting the "F12" button to see the web inspector console. It'll open up a whole new world. Click on the "console" menu item and click the button - it'll tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

It's because there's no `button` tags in your form. Use the attribute selector like so instead:

```
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of similar code by me involving a button triggering a function

The button:

```
 <button onclick="theFunction()">sampletext</button>
```

The script:

```
    var x = document.getElementById("sampleElement");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

In my example, the button is used to show/hide a div. Clicking my button triggers the function which changes the div visibility.